# Android ImageButton onClick

Tags: android

I have problem with button in activity_main.xml,

1. I need to launch by click on "imageButton8" a webView (website URL) in application.

> MainActivity.Java

```
package com.XX.app;

import com.XX.app.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView view;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Empêcher le téléphone de passer en mode veille
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        //When User click on the button imageButton8 the Activity2 launch
        Button imageButton8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
                setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            });
            }

    private void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    //loads RETURN URL on lastpage
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(this.view.canGoBack()) 
    {
        this.view.goBack();

    } else {
         new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("إغلاق تطبيق جمعية البر و التعاون")
            .setMessage("هل أنت متأكد أنك تريد إغلاق تطبيق جمعية البر و التعاون ؟")
            .setPositiveButton("نعم", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("لا", null)
        .show();
    }

  }

}
```

> activity_main.xml for imageButton8 is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_1">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
    android:onClick="click"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_www" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Activity2.java

```
package com.XX.app;

import com.XX.app.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    }
}
```

> activity_webview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_1">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

In the same project,
2. Others Issues: I have 08 buttons. How do I execute each button in its template xml?

For example: Button 1 => about_obama.xml. When user click (in this file) it will find the description of obama.
   Button 2 => ....xml...etc!
   Button 3......

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the onclickListener for the ImageButton using the ImageButton's setOnClickListener() method. So, in your MainActivity, inside your onCreate() method, do the following:

```
Button imageButton8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
// Set the OnClickListener on the button itself
imageButton8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class); // Use the MainActivity context
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
// You should delete the private setOnClickListener() method as it does not
// have any purpose
```

To specify the onClick() in the xml when the Button is clicked, set the:

```
android:onClick:"some_method"
```

property for your button. Then declare and define this method in your Activity.